# Why does my iptables port forward not work?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, amazon-ami

I'm trying to setup a port forwarding from port `80` to port `8080` on my amazon linux ami machine.

I ran

```
$ sudo /sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

And verified the results:

```
$ sudo iptables --table nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

However requesting port `80` does not work:

```
$ wget http://localhost:80
--2017-09-25 08:51:27--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

Whereas port `8080` works fine:

```
$ wget http://localhost:8080
--2017-09-25 08:51:39--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
```

How can I let port `80` be an alias for port `8080`?

---

Additional information:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

$ sudo sysctl -a | grep ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.stable_secret"
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
```

Comment: Did you run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`?

Comment: Also note that it might not work depending on the kernel, because **localhost** is not on **eth0** but on a **'lo'** interface and - depending on the kernel - the packets on **eht0** to **127.0.0.1** *might* or *might not* be interpreted as matching to this rule.

Comment: what does `sysctl -a | grep ip_forward` output then?

Comment: btw: I managed to echo 1 into `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` now, but it still does not solve the issue. @GeraldSchneider

Comment: @bocian85 I added the output to my question.

Comment: try to modify the rule and use **-i lo** instead of **-i eth0**, if you need it to work on external IP then don't use the localhost address to verify that it works, or modify it so that work for all addresses

Comment: @bocian85 Running it with `lo` (`sudo /sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`) did not change anything.

Comment: can you show `netstat -nlp | grep 8080` output ? 
Perhaps this application only listens on external IP

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the port forwarding was in effect, but did not work for `localhost`. However, accessing the port from outside worked perfectly.

I still do not know, *why* it did not work for `localhost` but it is not of importance for me currently.

Comment: most likely because your rule is only valid for the eth0 interface, but localhost connects through the lo device.